# Getting rid of Android API level error when I am managing the API level manually

Tags: android, lint, suppress-warnings

I have two sections of code to get the size of the display, one for API level > 13 and one that uses deprecated methods prior to that. I'm getting an error using the newer method because my min API level is set lower than required for it's use. Here is the code:

```
//Get display size
int API_Version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

if(API_Version >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
{
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    G.ScreenWidth = size.x;
    G.ScreenHeight = size.y;
}
else
{
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    G.ScreenWidth = display.getWidth();
    G.ScreenHeight = display.getHeight();
}
```

The error shows up on the line with the call to Display.getSize(). I know I can suppress the error at the class or function level, but is that the only way to get rid of it? Is there no way to tell LINT that I am handling it in-place in the code I posted? I guess I want to be able to suppress the error right in the most local scope so that it only applies there and is turned off outside of the "if" clause, like this:

```
if(API_Version >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
{
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    display.getSize(size);
    G.ScreenWidth = size.x;
    G.ScreenHeight = size.y;
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think you can do it directly on the line you want.

Comment: No. You can suppress Lint warnings per method or per class only.

Comment: Also, **please** use `@TargetApi(NN)`, not `@SuppressLint("NewApi")`. You have only validated that your code is correct through some API level (13 in this case). If you start using something newer than that, and you have failed to add in the appropriate version checks, `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` will not warn you.

Comment: Okay, thanks guys, and thank you CommonsWare I will update it as you suggested

Comment: Actually, CommonsWare, if you want to submit that as an answer I'll approve it or whatever it's called. My concern was applying the error suppression too broadly and potentially missing other errors or warning in other places in the code and your suggestion helps to prevent that.